# Can't connect to postgresql on local machine using IP + pgadmin

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

On Ubuntu 12.04, I've installed pg and pgadmin.

I can access **localhost/phppgadmin** using the browser.

I also can do this: **IP/phppgadmin**.

However, I cannot use the IP number to connect to pg using pgadmin.

It reports that the server isn't listening.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL by default listen only on local UNIX sockect.  To enable TCP/IP endpoint uncomment in your postgresql.conf file:

listen_addresses = '*'

Where '*' - listen on all interfaces. Or put your IP number here if you want listen on specific IP only.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I've done but it doesn't work. I tried putting my IP, then tried IP/subnet, and then tried '*' but nothing works, except localhost.

Comment: I would add that you can use localhost instead of ip to connect using pgadmin without changing anything

Comment: @Hex yes I can for locally testing but I'm trying to create a Lazarus (pascal) program and it will run on PCs within the LAN. So I need to be able to specify the IP to my server.

Comment: Do you restarted your pgsql server? And check your firewall and look at output: netstat -ltpn. Is there tcp port 5432 on listen state?

Comment: @Hex yes, it's listening on port 5432. I did not setup any firewall. And yes, both pg and apache have been restarted a few times (after config changes at least).

Comment: @RJS Sorry for my ignorance... Part of the problem was to do with the listen_addresses... I HAD put an asterisk (*) but later realised that the line was **commented** by default. Removing the comments partially solved the problem. Thanks! +1 for that...

Answer (score 1):

What's the error message you get from PGAdmin? Is there anything in the logs (`/var/log/postgresql.log` or similar)?

I would guess you have no proper auth-setting in your [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), as PostgreSQL per default only allows local users via unix-sockets to connect, not via TCP which you want. You might need something like

```
host       all  all  0.0.0.0  pam
```

or

```
hostssl       all  all  0.0.0.0  md5
```

in the `pg_hba.conf` -- read the above link for proper documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to the different users who helped me narrow down the problem. Actually there were multiple issues. I have outline them here as a complete answer and hope someone else may benefit.

1. like RJS said, I had to put the listen_addresses to accept multiple IPs. This was initially done but later on I realised that the line had a # in front of it which meant it was commented. So I took off the comment.
2. Even after stopping the PG server, `pg_lsclusters` showed that there was still a service running. So I couldn't restart it since it reported that it  was already running.
3. Then by using `ps` I found that a related program known as `pgpool` was using the same port and it wouldn't let the default **5432** port to be used by PG. So I stopped this from the terminal using `sudo pgpool stop`.
4. Then I restarted the postgres server and all was fine!

   While searching for an answer, I was told by a volunteer *RhodiumToad* on IRC (#postgresql) that pooling wasn't necessary for what I was doing. I was asked why I have it. The strange thing is that I never installed it. Perhaps pgpool was installed as some addition.
5. One of the other problems was that I could not get pgadmin to start up on Windows. and correctly connect. There was a libpq.dll missing. Apparently (you'll find another post on stackoverflow about this), the file was there in a few places on Win XP. So I copied all of the postgres DLL files to Windows/System32 and it fixed that.

That's it! Hope this helps.